# Error while searching for Xcode SDK: timed out waiting for shell command to complete

Tags: xcode, sdk

I got this error "Error while searching for Xcode SDK: timed out waiting for shell command to complete" suddenly.

Xcode Version  is 14.3.1

There is no specific name of SDK so I don't know how to fix it , any idea about that?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?? I am having same issue.